# docker-compose "up" vs. "run" yields different mounted volume

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose

### Update 2: I have created [a sample project on Git to reproduce this issue](https://github.com/twelve17/dc-test).   Upon further testing, the test case is slightly different than what I've described in my original post.

I am including the contents of the README I wrote on the github repo below.

---

## Use Case

- One simple nodejs project with a `Dockerfile`.
- One local NPM dependency used by the above project (copied to container via Dockerfile). The project refers to the dependency via a [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths).
- The nodejs project has one web route (`/`) that prints the version of the local npm dependency from its `package.json`.  This is used to verify the results of the test case procedure.
- docker-compose uses [this volume technique](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) to overlay the host machine's source tree
  on top of the container's source tree and then overlaying the `node_modules` from the container on top of the first volume.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Clone [this repo](https://github.com/twelve17/dc-test).
2. Clean up any previous containers and images related to this repo's project via `docker rm` and `docker rmi`.
3. Check out the `test2_run1` tag. This state represents the project using version 1.0.0 of the local NPM dependency.
4. Do a `docker-compose build`.  All steps should run without any cache usage if step 2 was followed correctly.
   Note the version of the local NPM dependency during the `npm install` command, e.g. `+-- my-npm@1.0.0`.
5. Do a `docker-compose up`.  Browse to `http://localhost:8000`.  The page should report version `1.0.0`.
6. Stop the running containers. (Ctrl-C on the terminal from which the `up` command was issued.)
7. Check out the `test2_run2` tag. This introduces [a small change](https://github.com/twelve17/dc-test/compare/test2_run1...test2_run2) to the NPM's `index.js` file, and a version
   bump in its `package.json` to `1.0.1`.
8. Do a `docker-compose build`.  **Only the instructions up to `COPY ./my-npm ...` should use a cache.** (E.g., the docker output prints `---> Using cache` for that instruction.)  All subsequent steps should be run by docker.  This is because the changes introduced in step 7 to the NPM package should have invalidated the cache for the `COPY ./my-npm ...` command, and, as a result, subsequent steps too.  Confirm that during the `npm install` command, the new version of the NPM is printed in the summary tree output, e.g. `+-- my-npm@1.0.1`.
9. Do a `docker-compose up`.  Browse to `http://localhost:8000`.  The page should report version `1.0.1`.

Expected behavior: Page in step 9 should report `1.0.1`.  That is, a change in the local npm should be reflected in the container via `docker-compose up`.

Actual behavior: Page in step 9 reports `1.0.0`.

**Note that docker itself is re-building images as expected.**  The observed issue is not that docker is re-using a cached image, as the output
shows it re-running NPM install and showing the new version of the local NPM dependency.  The issue is that `docker-compose` is not seeing
that the underlying images that comprise the `dctest_service1` container have been updated.

In fact, running bash in the container allows us to see that the container has the updated `my-npm` module files, but the `node_modules`
version is stale:

`# docker exec -it dctest_service1_1 bash
  app@6bf2671b75c6:~/service1$ grep version  my-npm/package.json  node_modules/my-npm/package.json
  my-npm/package.json:  "version": "1.0.1",
  node_modules/my-npm/package.json:  "version": "1.0.0"
  app@6bf2671b75c6:~/service1$`

Workaround: Use `docker rm` to remove the `dctest_service1` container.  Then re-run `docker-compose up`, which will re-create the container using the existing images.  Notable in this step is that no underlying images are re-built.  In re-creating the container, `docker-compose` seems to figure out to use the newer volume that has the updated `node_modules`.

See the [`output`](https://github.com/twelve17/dc-test/tree/master/output) directory for the output printed during the first run (steps 4 and 5) and the second run (steps 8 and 9).

---

#### Original Post

I've got a `nodejs` `Dockerfile` based on [this tutorial ("Lessons from Building a Node App in Docker")](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html).  Specifically, note that this tutorial uses a volume trick to mount the `node_modules` directory from the container itself to overlay on top of the equivalent one from the host machine. E.g.:

```
volumes:
 - .:/home/app/my-app
 - /home/app/my-app/node_modules
```

I am running into a problem where an update to package.json is triggering a `npm install` as expected (as opposed to using the docker cache), but when starting the service with `docker-compose up`, the resulting container somehow ends up with an older version of the `node_modules` data, as the newly added NPM package that had been added is missing from the directory.  Yet, if run the specified `CMD` by hand via `docker-compose run --rm`, then I **do** see the updated volume!

I can confirm this a few ways:

#### `node_modules` Timestamp

Container started via "up":

```
app@88614c5599b6:~/my-app$ ls -l
...
drwxr-xr-x 743 app app 28672 Dec 12 16:41 node_modules
```

Container started via "run":

```
app@bdcbfb37b4ba:~/my-app$ ls -l
...
drwxr-xr-x 737 app app 28672 Jan  9 02:25 node_modules
```

#### Different `docker inspect` "Mount" entry Id

Container started via "up":

```
"Name": "180b82101433ab159a46ec1dd0edb9673bcaf09c98e7481aed7a32a87a94e76a",
"Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/180b82101433ab159a46ec1dd0edb9673bcaf09c98e7481aed7a32a87a94e76a/_data",
"Destination": "/home/app/my-app/node_modules",
```

Container started via "run":

```
"Name": "8eb7454fb976830c389b54f9480b1128ab15de14ca0b167df8f3ce880fb55720",
"Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/8eb7454fb976830c389b54f9480b1128ab15de14ca0b167df8f3ce880fb55720/_data",
"Destination": "/home/app/my-app/node_modules",
```

### HostConfig -> Binds

I am unsure if this is related, but I also did notice (also in `docker inspect`) that the `Binds` section under `HostConfig` differs between both cases:

Container started via "up":

```
"Binds": [
   "180b82101433ab159a46ec1dd0edb9673bcaf09c98e7481aed7a32a87a94e76a:/home/app/my-app/node_modules:rw",
  "/Volumes/my-mount/my-app:/home/app/my-app:rw"
],
```

Container started via "run":

```
"Binds": [
  "/Volumes/my-mount/my-app:/home/app/my-app:rw"
],
```

(Both show the host source mounted on the image, but only the "up" shows the secondary overlay volume with `node_modules`, which seems like another odd wrinkle.)

### Theory

Per the [docker-compose CLI reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/):

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s
>   configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation,
>   docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the
>   containers

Thus, it appears `docker-compose up` does not think the configuration or image was changed.  I am just not sure how to debug this to confirm.  Of course, I could use `--force-recreate` to work around this, but I wish to resolve what about my configuration is incorrect that is causing the problem.

**Update**: If I do an explicit `docker-compose build` prior to `docker-compose up`, the problem still persists.  Thus I am feeling less confident about this theory at the moment.

Here is the entire `Dockefile`:

```
FROM node:6.9.1

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app

ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP=my-app
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli

COPY ./package.json $HOME/$APP/package.json
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

USER app
WORKDIR $HOME/$APP
RUN npm install && npm cache clean

USER root
COPY . $HOME/$APP
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/* && chmod u+x ./node_modules/.bin/* ./bin/*

USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/my-app/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Comment: Could you post your `docker-compose.yml` file too? so we can compare that file with your `Dockerfile`. See my answer below

Comment: @Pitt the file is quite big.  That being said, I have noticed that if I delete the container via "docker rm <x>", then when d-c builds, it uses the correct images to create the container.  So something about d-c is causing it to not realize the underlying images have been changed.  I am going to create a smaller/simpler project to try and reproduce.

Comment: I looked closer at the tutorial you linked, if your docker-compose.yml uses the uses the directive `build: .` it means that rather than using only a pre-build image to instantiate your docker container it will build the `.` (current) directory. So if you change something you'd have to run `docker-compose build` before running `docker-compose run` otherwise an older, cached build is used.

Comment: Also if you just want to use one command you can use `docker-compose up --build`.

To really see what is going on, you'd have to post your full `docker run` command that you use, as well as your `docker-compose` command and `docker-compose.yml` file that defines the service you are wanting to run.

Comment: @Pitt - I'm not sure if you saw my "update" - but it appears that a build, whether explicit or not, does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Pitt I appreciate you helping out here, but let me try and set up a simpler project to help debug this.

Comment: okay! One last thing: I noticed that your question is not clear as to whether you are using `docker run` or `docker-compose run`. so maybe a more adequate test would be to compare the results of `docker start` with `docker-compose up`, and `docker run` with `docker-compose run`?

Comment: @Pitt I am using `docker-compose up`.  If I use `docker-compose run`, it works because it creates a new container with the proper images.  

I've updated the post with a link to a sample project to reproduce, along with instructions.  I think I will try reaching out to docker devs for help too.

Answer (score 2):

the command `docker-compose` uses the docker-compose.yml file as a configuration file of your containered `service`. By default it looks for this .yml config file in the directory you run `docker-compose`. 
So it could be that your docker-compose.yml file is not up to date, seeing that one of your volumes is not mounted when you run `docker-compose up`.

`docker run` ignores the docker-compose.yml file and just builds the container using the `Dockerimage`. So there could be configuration difference between the `Dockerimage` file and the `docker-compose.yml` files.